# Why am I getting "Control does not support transparent background colors"?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a C# - Winforms application and attempting to set the background colour of a read-only text box like so...

```
txtMyBox.BackColor = Color.FromName ("Red");
```

This is failing with the error message...

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
Message=Control does not support transparent background colors.
Source=System.Windows.Forms
```

First things first; is this the right way to set the background colour for a read-only textbox? I'm doing this a lot for ordinary textboxes and it appears to work fine.

If it is, could someone help me out with what a "transparent background color" is, and why I should want one? I don't think I do; I just want the background to change colour.

Comment: Everything is in documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx

Comment: If you would type the Message in google, then 3rd link is exact duplicate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way would be:

```
txtMyBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

The error you getting is being caused because of somewhere else in your code where you are trying to set the background color of the form itself to be transparent and that is not supported, check your code carefully and you will find somthing like that:

```
BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Since there is no element name (i.e. myControl.BackColor = somthing) and your sentence start with BackColor = somthing - the compiler thinks you want to change the background color of the windows form into being transparent, check your form editor too - you might doing that from there.

Here is a reproduction of your error:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackColor = Color.Transparent; //Control does not support transparent background colors.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't find the word "transparent" in any file associated with the solution.

Comment: It might exist as Color from ARGB(0,255,255,255). check carefully - i promise it is there somewhere. another way is trying to set Backcolor = 0

Comment: Righto. I'll have another try tomorrow. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You were right; it was well-hidden but I finally tracked it down (`BackColor = Color.FromColor("Some Colour that Doesn't Exist")`). Thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

Quite old post but... Have you tried this before?

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late - but eventually helps this someone who - like me - found this page according to the OPs question:

I got this error when Setting a Winforms Splitter background color which was generated by a

```
Color.FromArgb(0xC9,0xD9,0xEB);
```

The solution was to generate the Color value instead with the following helper method:

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C9D9EB")
```

This avoids generating a transparency Information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of `FromName`

```
 txtMyBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: That is static nethod that still return color. Is not good to use if not required. But the answer is more about SupportsTransparentBackColor that is set to false instead of true.

Comment: No, he doesn't want a transparent background. He's getting an error when trying to set the background color.

Comment: I really believe more to compiler than user.

Answer (score 0):

```
ColorTextBox.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
textBox2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(
                     ColorTextBox.BackColor.ToArgb());
```