# How to Change Form background color in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, colors

I am using following code in `form_load` event to change `Form.BackgroundColor`, but it is giving me an error.

> Control does not support transparent background colors.

Here is what I am trying...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string sColor = "#ACE1AF";// Hex value of any color
  Int32 iColorInt = Convert.ToInt32(sColor.Substring(1), 16);
  Color curveColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(iColorInt);
  this.BackColor = curveColor;
 }
```

I found the same question ([Why am I getting "Control does not support transparent background colors"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586322/why-am-i-getting-control-does-not-support-transparent-background-colors)), but is not met my requirement due to in this `Color` class is using its default values.

Comment: I find same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/winforms-making-a-control-transparent

Comment: I am not trying to make form transprent, I want to change only color from Hex value

Comment: ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FEF2D4");

Comment: @isxaker please make it as answer, so i can Accept it. its worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#00FEF2D4");
```

Edit :
`ColorTranslator.FromHtml` Translates an HTML color representation to a GDI+ `Color` structure.

> Parameters
>
> htmlColor
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The string representation of the Html color to translate.
>
> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Drawing.Color
>
> The Color structure that represents the translated HTML color or Empty if 
>   htmlColor is null.

Comment: Please explain your code (even if it's really simple) or provide the reference to your function. Code-only answer is discouraged since it may confuse not only OP, but also future readers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you *are* trying to make the background transparent. The color you specify in ARGB is 100% transparent. Hence the error.

You should use:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sColor = "#FFACE1AF";// Hex value of any color
    Int32 iColorInt = Convert.ToInt32(sColor.Substring(1), 16);
    Color curveColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(iColorInt);
    this.BackColor = curveColor;
}
```

Setting the alpha channel to `FF`.