# C# Custom textBox design

Tags: c#, colors, textbox

I want to customize a textBox in C# and I have a problem. If I set

```
 textBox1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

I receive error:

> `Additional information: Control does not support transparent background colors.`

I tried to insert in constructor

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

but didn't solve anything. I have installed Dev Express but I don't know if it helps. Some ideas?
Constructor:

```
public Constructor()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# transparency on textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16050249/c-sharp-transparency-on-textbox)

Comment: is not duplicate, I already seen that

Comment: So your question is *why is my subclassed textbox ignoring transparency*? Show the constructor

Answer (score 0):

Is this a duplicate question??

[Why am I getting "Control does not support transparent background colors"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586322/why-am-i-getting-control-does-not-support-transparent-background-colors)

I don't think that winforms support transparent background colors.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose of a transparent textbox control??

Comment: just for design. I want it with border and with no background color

Comment: _There has to be an solution_ Why do you think so? Maybe there isn't! -  You could write one all from scratch but the `TextBox` is a rather unfriendly beast that doesn't lend itself well to re-styling..

Comment: I understand you want it. Why do you want it? Is there something you want to show in the textbox? Do you want the user to be able to see the text or an image behind it. You just want to force windows/UI/whatever to do something it won't do? I'm not trying to be nosy. I'm trying to understand your purpose. There's always more than one way to skin a cat. Question is why

Comment: I said that, because `Transparent` option is not there for nothing. It has a role.

Comment: Aaa I see. Well in that textBox, user will insert his username for login in program.

Comment: No, it may well be there as a leftover from the base class that has no function in TextBox!